# The command line output should be updated at the desired locations

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following content in `testfile.txt`.

```
[client]

clientName = 

[servername]

targetUri = contact support team
```

The file should get updated with the output of `hostname -s` at the end of `clientName =` line and example.com should be updated at the end of `targetUri =`, By removing "contact support team".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sai, try following:

```
awk -vHOST=$(hostname -s) '/clientName =/{print $0 FS HOST;;next} /targetUri/{gsub(/contact support team/,HOST,$0);print;next} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file
```

So here I am substituting the clientName = with it's value and box's name along with (contact support team) string's value with box's name, then I am putting this into a temp file and then renaming that temp file into real Input_file.

**EDIT:** changing a little code as per OP's code.

```
awk -vHOST=$(hostname -s) '/clientName =/{$0=$0 FS HOST;print;next} /targetUri/{gsub(/contact support team/,"example.com",$0);print;next} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file
```

**EDIT2:** @Sai, kindly go through the following.

```
awk -vHOST=$(hostname -s)    #### creating a variable named HOST whose value is command's hostname -s's value.
 '/clientName =/             #### searching for string clientName = in every line and if this string found then do following.
{print $0 FS HOST            #### printing the value of current line along with the FS field separator with value of HOST variable here.
;next}                       #### putting next here for skipping all further statements here.
/targetUri/                  #### search for string targetUri for every line and if string found in any line then do following.
{gsub(/contact support team/,"example.com",$0);  #### substitute the value of string (contact support team) to "example.com" in that line then.
print;                                           #### print the newly formed line(which as example.com value in it).
next                                             #### using next keyword I am requesting awk not to proceed with further statements now.
} 1'                         #### awk works on condition{action} method, so if any condition is TRUE then action following it should work
                                  so by putting 1 I am making condition as TRUE and not mentioning any action so by default action print will happen.
Input_file > temp_file       #### put all the processed output into temp_file file.
&& mv temp_file  Input_file  #### &&(if previous awk command ran successfully then do this command) rename temp_file to Input_file now.
```

Comment: It worked only with updating clientName but not replacing "contact support team" with example.com.

Comment: @Sai: I have changed the code now, kindly have a look to it.

Comment: @Sai, glad that it worked, you could mark is as a correct or helpful answer.

Comment: Can you explain how does it work? /clientName =/{$0=$0 FS HOST;print;next} /targetUri/{gsub(/contact support team/,"example.com",$0);print;next} 1

Comment: I have edited my answer now, please go through it and let me know on same.

Answer (score 1):

try this oneliner:

```
sed "/^clientName\b/{s/=.*/= $(hostname -s)/};/^targetUri\b/{s/=.*/= example.com/}" file
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked, But can you explain how does this work "\b/{s/=.*/=" in substitution. Also, can this be achieved using Awk command?

Comment: @Sai, could you please try my command and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @Sai yes it can. but you tagged with `sed and awk`. In short: it finds out the line and replace `=.....` with new value.